# Error Logging in C# Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, logging, error-handling

I am planning to implement error logging writing something similar to [this](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=94):

```
public static void WriteError(string errorMessage)
    {
        try
        {
            string path = "~/Error/" + DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-mm-yy") + ".txt";
            if (!File.Exists(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path)))
            {
                File.Create(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path)).Close();
            }
            using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path)))
            {
                w.WriteLine("\r\nLog Entry : ");
                w.WriteLine("{0}", DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                string err = "Error in: " + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString() +
                              ". Error Message:" + errorMessage;
                w.WriteLine(err);
                w.WriteLine("__________________________");
                w.Flush();
                w.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteError(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

My question is this: Since it is a website, I will have multiple users simultaneously. In that case, if multiple users encounter exceptions at the same time and try to write to the same file, it will again give me an exception right? In that case, how do I implement error logging correctly for simultaneous users? Or will this work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Great Idea to log errors, terrible idea to try to roll your own logging framework. As mentioned in the answer, check out log4net - super easy to use and amazingly flexible to adjust logging via config settings. Additionally it provides great support for logging warnings and other information, not just errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside using NLog or other log library, the way you lock this cases is with mutex. I suggest `mutex`, and not `lock()` because can catch all pools/threads that may throw an error.

On MSDN there are the details about `mutex` and examples:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx

a simple example

```
public static void WriteError(string errorMessage)
{
    var mut = new Mutex(true, "LogMutexName");

    try
    {   
        // Wait until it is safe to enter.
        mut.WaitOne();

        // here you open write close your file
    }
    finally
    {
        // Release the Mutex.
        mut.ReleaseMutex();
    }   
}
```

Comment: i'll most likely go with log4net but nice to know how to overcome that particular problem myself! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend you use an established logging framework such as [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) or [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/). I have used log4net on many projects in the past and it handles this scenario perfectly.

EDIT:

Just as a further comment, as well as handling log messages from multiple threads log4net also allows you to manage how large your log files grow and provide a built in rolling log mechanism via the [RollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.html).

Comment: thanks i'll go through the suggested frameworks and choose one!